# How can I add a local group to Publishing Point with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, acl

I'm trying to figure out how to add a local group to an (On-Demand) Publishing Point, with vbscript.

The group just needs read access to it. The group has (of course) been created first.

System: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 with Media Services 2008 (for R2). It's not a Domain Controller, there's no Active Directory.

Context: Running a media server with one Pub. Point per movie, and use the group to allow/deny access to that Pub. Point / movie on a per-user basis.
I can add the group manually, but I would really like to do it with a (vb)script.

To do it manually:
(first create a local group).
In Server Manager, click the on-demand Publishing Point, Properties tab, Authorization, WMS Publishing Points ACL Authorization (which of course has to be enabled), right-click it - choose Properties.
Strangely, Groups are by default not enabled in Object Types, so one has to specifically enable them to be able to add the group.

The closest example I've been able to find is this: (it's in VB.Net)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875036%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

My (almost-working) script so far:

```
Dim Server
Dim ODPubPoint
Dim Plugin
Dim ACLCheckAdmin
Dim AccessCtrlList
Dim objACE

' Create a new WMSServer object.
Set Server = CreateObject("WMSServer.server","localhost")

' Create a new ODPubPoint object.
Set ODPubPoint = Server.PublishingPoints.Item("supersizeme")

' Retrieve the plug-in to be configured.
Set Plugin = ODPubPoint.EventHandlers.Item("WMS Publishing Points ACL Authorization")

' Retrieve the custom interface of the plug-in.
Set ACLCheckAdmin = Plugin.CustomInterface

' Retrieve the list of access control entries.
Set AccessCtrlList = ACLCheckAdmin.AccessControlList

' Create an object to be able to add to the access control list.
Set objACE = CreateObject("AccessControlEntry")

objACE = AccessCtrlList.Add("MEDIESERVER\hest", 16 )
```

The group does get added, but the script dies with an error:
ppaddgroup.vbs(27, 2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method.
In the VB.Net example it says WMS_ACCESS_CONTROL.WMS_ACL_ALLOW_ALL which I have no idea how to convert from VB.Net to VBScript. I thought it was just a constant, but apparently not.
(and I just want to allow read access, as in WMS_ACL_ALLOW_READ ).

I found the constants on this page:
http://include.wutils.com/com-dll/constants/constants-WMSServerLib.htm

Can anyone come up with the correct way to add a group to a publishing point?

Comment: Consider adding your solution as the accepted answer, rather than an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Per [greylion's previous edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8064012/2):

> The last line needs to be:
>
> `Set objACE = AccessCtrlList.Add("MEDIESERVER\test", 16 )`
>
> For some reason, I was convinced that the final act of adding the
>   group was not supposed to have a "Set" in front. I thought it was only
>   for creating or defining objects, but apparently it's also for filling
>   them with actual data. Annoyingly, it almost worked with "Set"
>   missing, which led me to think I just had some minor detail wrong, but
>   no way to know what it was.
>
> Mental note: Filling an object with data is NOT like setting a
>   variable or constant.